# How to get node text from child context using ruby, xpath, rexml

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, rexml

I'm having an issue getting `REXML::XPath.first` to render the correct node text from a child context.

See the test script and xml below.

**test.rb**

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'rexml/xpath'

file = File.new('test.xml')
doc = REXML::Document.new(file)

employers = REXML::XPath.match(doc, '//EmployerOrg')
employers.each do |employer|
  # this looks fine, position_history is being set for each employer
  position_history = REXML::XPath.first(employer, 'PositionHistory')

  # always returns the title from the first employer, in spite of the position_history context
  p title = REXML::XPath.first(position_history, '//Title').text
end
```

**Output:**

```
"Director of Web Applications Development"
"Director of Web Applications Development"
"Director of Web Applications Development"
```

**Example XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Resume xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2006-02-28" xmlns:sov="http://sovren.com/hr-xml/2006-02-28">
  <StructuredXMLResume>
    <EmploymentHistory>
      <EmployerOrg>
        <EmployerOrgName>Technical Difference</EmployerOrgName>
        <PositionHistory positionType="directHire" currentEmployer="true">
          <Title>Director of Web Applications Development</Title>
          <OrgName>
            <OrganizationName>Technical Difference</OrganizationName>
          </OrgName>
          <StartDate>
            <AnyDate>2004-10-01</AnyDate>
          </StartDate>
          <EndDate>
            <AnyDate>2015-09-15</AnyDate>
          </EndDate>
        </PositionHistory>
      </EmployerOrg>
      <EmployerOrg>
        <EmployerOrgName>Convergence Inc. LLC</EmployerOrgName>
        <PositionHistory positionType="directHire">
          <Title>Senior Web Developer/DBA</Title>
          <OrgName>
            <OrganizationName>Convergence Inc. LLC</OrganizationName>
          </OrgName>
          <StartDate>
            <AnyDate>2003-03-01</AnyDate>
          </StartDate>
          <EndDate>
            <AnyDate>2004-12-01</AnyDate>
          </EndDate>
          <UserArea>
            <sov:PositionHistoryUserArea>
              <sov:Id>POS-2</sov:Id>
              <sov:CompanyNameProbability>23</sov:CompanyNameProbability>
              <sov:PositionTitleProbability>30</sov:PositionTitleProbability>
            </sov:PositionHistoryUserArea>
          </UserArea>
        </PositionHistory>
      </EmployerOrg>
      <EmployerOrg>
        <EmployerOrgName>Avalon Digital Marketing Systems, Inc</EmployerOrgName>
        <PositionHistory positionType="contract">
          <Title>Contractor - Web Development</Title>
          <OrgName>
            <OrganizationName>Avalon Digital Marketing Systems, Inc</OrganizationName>
          </OrgName>
          <StartDate>
            <AnyDate>2002-05-01</AnyDate>
          </StartDate>
          <EndDate>
            <AnyDate>2003-03-01</AnyDate>
          </EndDate>
        </PositionHistory>
        <PositionHistory positionType="directHire">
          <Title>Web Developer/Junior DBA</Title>
          <OrgName>
            <OrganizationName>European Division</OrganizationName>
          </OrgName>
          <StartDate>
            <AnyDate>2000-05-01</AnyDate>
          </StartDate>
          <EndDate>
            <AnyDate>2002-04-30</AnyDate>
          </EndDate>
        </PositionHistory>
      </EmployerOrg>
    </EmploymentHistory>
  </StructuredXMLResume>
</Resume>
```

Comment: Rather than use REXML, use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), which is the defacto standard for XML/HTML parsing with Ruby and has a nice generator using its [Builder](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder) API.

Comment: defacto standard? REXML is in the stdlib and I'd like to avoid adding a new dependency.

Comment: @theTinMan, I think you're right in popularity terms, SO can be a rough guide to judge popularity (120 q, 2 followers for REXML and 2557 q. with 135 followers for Nokogiri). Though suggesting another tool to do the job is not always a suitable answer...

Comment: Part of the task of helping is recommending improvements and better ways to do things. Simply answering the question at hand often leads to lousy code that works poorly instead of code that is done clearly, cleanly and is maintainable. REXML is bundled with Ruby but that hardly means it's the fastest or most robust or well-documented. It's the historical offering, but other packages have been replaced over the years so it could end up that way too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because your XPath `'//Title'` is saying to start at the top of the document, pretty much ignoring the context-node `position_history`.  Try replacing that with `'./Title'` or just `'Title'`.

Comment: Both `'Title'` and `'./Title'` work. Thanks! Would be interesting to know why `//` is starting at the top of the document and not the context that I passed in. This is what tripped me up.

Comment: Because the document only gets parsed once, and functions are returning what you should consider pointers or sets of pointers to nodes in that one parsed document.  You can think about it like you think about your current working directory at a command prompt.  if I say (Unix format) `ls /`, it's going to list the root directory no matter where on the filesystem tree I am.